# Anyone used xemail-net for c#?

Tags: c#, imap

I'm trying to find out how to use xemail-net, I downloaded it and it has the source but no dll which I can add to reference. If you have used it please let me know how I can add it to my current project.

Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just build the source and reference the DLL that is built?